# OpenCV: Mobotix camera feed delay

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, ip-camera

I have a Mobotix c25 camera. It is an IP Camera, and I access to its stream in this way:

```
Mat frame;
cv::VideoCapture vcap;
if(!vcap.open("http://(IP_address)/cgi-bin/faststream.jpg?stream=full&fps=25.0&data=v.mjpg")){  
       cout<<"Camera not found"<<endl;        
}
```

As you can see I have selected 25 frames per second. I want to save every one of them. I do this with:

```
while (true){           
    vcap >> frame;
    frameNumber++;

    string fullPath = "Frame";
    stringstream ss;
    ss << frameNumber;
    string num = ss.str();
    fullPath.append(num);
    fullPath.append(".jpg");
}
```

However, I only save two frames per second because the next line takes approximately 400 ms:

> vcap >> frame;

I do not know why I have such a big delay... I tend to think that is a problem produced by the parameters of the camera, do you have any thoughts on this?

Thanks in advance.

NOTE: I don't know if it is important but I am using the port 80 of the camera.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this. The link I was using was grabbing the image using guest access.

By default the guest access is limited to 2 fps. I have changed this in the "Admin Menu“ of the camera at "Language and Start Page" -> "Refresh Rate for Guest Access" and now I can capture 25 frames per second.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mess with the guest user you can simply replace "cgi-bin" with "control" in your URL to retrieve an unrestricted live stream.